# How to Update AJAX Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I use the following code to edit But despite the success of editing the message is not stored in the database, where is the problem?

my controller:

```
public function patchUpdate($id, messageRequest $request)
{
    try {
        $category = Category::findOrNew($id);
        $category->update($request->all());
        return response()->json(['sms' => 'ok']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $request->messages();
    }
}
```

my Ajax code:

```
$('#submitUpdate').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var cat = $('#updateForm').serialize();
            var id = $('#updateForm').attr('placeholder');
            var token = $('input[name="_token"]').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/update') }}" + '/' + id + '',
                type: 'post',
                data: {"id": id, '_token': token, 'cat': cat},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.sms);
                }
            });
        });
```

my Route code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::auth();
Route::post('update/{id}', ['as' => 'update/{id}',  'uses' =>        'categoryController@patchUpdate']);
});
```

Comment: sorry my answer was wrong... questions 1) what do u mean success of editing message? and 2) have you dumped the $request->all() to double check it is the proper format for your model?

Comment: yes this Subject is Already

Comment: hove to fix this ?

Comment: this code work But not set to Database :(

Answer (score 0):

Check if your model has mass assignable attributes with the same name of inputs.

```
class Categories extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```